# Merge cells with the same value in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, merge, looker-studio

I am generating a `Data Studio` from a `google sheet`, the problem is that when combining several cells in the Data Studio it only collects the first related value and the others
show as null

This is my sheet:

[image]

This is what the Data Studio shows:

[image]

What I want to do is merge column A but show all four cells in column B

**Update**
This is the formula I added:

[image]

Comment: merging stuff is possible only with script

Comment: @player0 I don't understand this, what is script?, how can I do what I'm trying from the google sheets?

Comment: not sure if you are familiar with Excel, but there you have 2 options - either to use internal formula or to use VBA script. google sheets is same... you can either use internal formula or custom script which is written in JS - see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPJ-2U45BpA

Answer (score 1):

I recommand to not merge cells but use a conditional formatting rule as

```
=A2=A1
```

applicable to A2:A, with white font color

[image]

Comment: This function returns `false` and does nothing, I have updated the question with the formula

Comment: @segmet but it appears to work in your screenshot?

Comment: no, cell A3 does not contain anything, as you can see in the capture that I have put, using the same formula that you are using, it only returns a false but does nothing

Comment: share a spreadsheet, maybe there is a misunderstanding (my goal is to "hide" information when these infirmations are the same as the cell above)